# qwt cannot build Windows 8 64 bit

Tags: qt, qwt

I have installed `Qt5.5.1` on Windows 8 and the compiler is `MSVC2013 64 bit`, now I need to integrate qwt with Qt

I am following the instruction [here](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html#qwtinstall-windows), as a first step downloaded qwt source and extracted it, then  opened Qt5.5 64bit(MASVC 2013) command prompt and run the command

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\qmake.exe qwt.pro
```

Which end with no error.

Now I open Visual studio x64 Win64 Command prompt(2010) and run

```
nmake
```

Which give following error

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x64 tools.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>E:

E:\>cd
E:\

E:\>cd Software\Qt\QWT\qwt-6.1.1

E:\Software\Qt\QWT\qwt-6.1.1>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cd src\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\qma
ke.exe E:\Software\Qt\QWT\qwt-6.1.1\src\src.pro -o Makefile ) && "C:\Program Fil
es (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe" -f Makefile

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.
exe" -f Makefile.Release all

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

compiling .\qwt_abstract_scale_draw.cpp .\qwt_clipper.cpp .\qwt_color_map.cpp .\
qwt_column_symbol.cpp .\qwt_date.cpp .\qwt_date_scale_draw.cpp .\qwt_date_scale_
engine.cpp .\qwt_dyngrid_layout.cpp .\qwt_event_pattern.cpp .\qwt_graphic.cpp .\
qwt_interval.cpp .\qwt_interval_symbol.cpp .\qwt_math.cpp .\qwt_magnifier.cpp .\
qwt_null_paintdevice.cpp .\qwt_painter.cpp .\qwt_painter_command.cpp .\qwt_panne
r.cpp .\qwt_picker.cpp .\qwt_picker_machine.cpp .\qwt_pixel_matrix.cpp .\qwt_poi
nt_3d.cpp .\qwt_point_polar.cpp .\qwt_round_scale_draw.cpp .\qwt_scale_div.cpp .
\qwt_scale_draw.cpp .\qwt_scale_map.cpp .\qwt_spline.cpp .\qwt_scale_engine.cpp
.\qwt_symbol.cpp .\qwt_system_clock.cpp .\qwt_text_engine.cpp .\qwt_text_label.c
pp .\qwt_text.cpp .\qwt_transform.cpp .\qwt_widget_overlay.cpp .\qwt_curve_fitte
r.cpp .\qwt_abstract_legend.cpp .\qwt_legend.cpp .\qwt_legend_data.cpp .\qwt_leg
end_label.cpp .\qwt_plot.cpp .\qwt_plot_renderer.cpp .\qwt_plot_xml.cpp .\qwt_pl
ot_axis.cpp .\qwt_plot_curve.cpp .\qwt_plot_dict.cpp .\qwt_plot_directpainter.cp
p .\qwt_plot_grid.cpp .\qwt_plot_histogram.cpp .\qwt_plot_item.cpp .\qwt_plot_ab
stract_barchart.cpp .\qwt_plot_barchart.cpp .\qwt_plot_multi_barchart.cpp .\qwt_
plot_intervalcurve.cpp .\qwt_plot_zoneitem.cpp .\qwt_plot_tradingcurve.cpp .\qwt
_plot_spectrogram.cpp .\qwt_plot_spectrocurve.cpp .\qwt_plot_scaleitem.cpp .\qwt
_plot_legenditem.cpp .\qwt_plot_seriesitem.cpp .\qwt_plot_shapeitem.cpp .\qwt_pl
ot_marker.cpp .\qwt_plot_textlabel.cpp .\qwt_plot_layout.cpp .\qwt_plot_canvas.c
pp .\qwt_plot_panner.cpp .\qwt_plot_rasteritem.cpp .\qwt_plot_picker.cpp .\qwt_p
lot_zoomer.cpp .\qwt_plot_magnifier.cpp .\qwt_plot_rescaler.cpp .\qwt_point_mapp
er.cpp .\qwt_raster_data.cpp .\qwt_matrix_raster_data.cpp .\qwt_sampling_thread.
cpp .\qwt_series_data.cpp .\qwt_point_data.cpp .\qwt_scale_widget.cpp .\qwt_plot
_svgitem.cpp .\qwt_plot_glcanvas.cpp .\qwt_abstract_slider.cpp .\qwt_abstract_sc
ale.cpp .\qwt_arrow_button.cpp .\qwt_analog_clock.cpp .\qwt_compass.cpp .\qwt_co
mpass_rose.cpp .\qwt_counter.cpp .\qwt_dial.cpp .\qwt_dial_needle.cpp .\qwt_knob
.cpp .\qwt_slider.cpp .\qwt_thermo.cpp .\qwt_wheel.cpp
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/FS'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'echo' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

E:\Software\Qt\QWT\qwt-6.1.1>
```

What could be the issue, my Qt using `MSVC2013 64 bit compiler`  and where as I running `nmake` using visual studio 2010 command prompt. Could that be the issue?
If so do I need to install Visual studio 2013?

I also tried jom using the command

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -j12
```

Which also end up with some error.

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks
Haris

Answer (score 1):

you need to open the command prompt like administrator.

And for be available to use the plugins, need to compile qwt in the same compiler that Qt Creator.